# How do I add system_filter on Debian Exim single file config?

Tags: debian, exim

I'm trying to add a system_filer on a single file configuration in Exim. 
The problems is that when running `update-exim4.conf` I'm getting `option "system_filter" unknown`. I have searched the file if there are macros to enable this option without success. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Exim has many sections in its configuration file. Where are you setting that option? If it's in the wrong location, this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exim.conf` file has a few sections. These start with the keyword `begin` followed by the section name; e.g., the `acl` section starts at the line `begin acl`, and ends at the next section (or the end of the file, whichever is first).

There is one extra section, the one that holds global options. This section does not start with a `begin` keyword; instead, it starts at the beginning of the file, and ends at the first `begin` keyword (i.e., at the next section).

The `system_filter` setting is a global setting, and therefore must be set in the global section of the file. Since you state that you put it at the end of the file, you did not do so.

Just place it somewhere near the top of the file, before the first line that starts with `begin`. It will work then.